# PHP Session changed every reload after Header set Set-Cookie Secure

Tags: php, apache, session, cookies

Recently a scan was run on one of our applications and it returned the following  security threats:

1.Cookies NotMarked As Secure::Cookie without Secure flag set
2.Cookie without HttpOnly flag set::Cookiewithout HttpOnly flag set

After we fixed this in our apache httpd.conf, our login doesn't work anymore.

```
Header set Set-Cookie HttpOnly
Header set Set-Cookie Secure
```

Now the session-id is changing every time the users reloads the website. 
The user is able to login, but after any navigation on this site, the user logged out because of a different session-id.

How can we fix this?